# Erlang release test failing on CentOS 7

Tags: erlang

Building Erlang on CentOS 7.  When running the release tests, the following test fails.

openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
otp 22.0

```
=== Test case: jinterface_SUITE:java_erlang_send_receive/1 (click for source code)

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: MboxSendReceive has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0


    .....


cmd res: 1


*** CT Error Notification 2019-05-15 17:10:42.287 ***
jinterface_SUITE:send_receive failed on line 766
Reason: {badmatch,{error,1}}

Full error description and stacktrace




=== Ended at 2019-05-15 17:10:42
=== Location: [{jinterface_SUITE,send_receive,766},
              {test_server,ts_tc,1748},
              {test_server,run_test_case_eval1,1263},
              {test_server,run_test_case_eval,1195}]
=== === Reason: no match of right hand side value {error,1}
  in function  jinterface_SUITE:send_receive/3 (jinterface_SUITE.erl, line 766)
  in call from test_server:ts_tc/3 (test_server.erl, line 1748)
  in call from test_server:run_test_case_eval1/6 (test_server.erl, line 1263)
  in call from test_server:run_test_case_eval/9 (test_server.erl, line 1195)
```

This is the only test that fails.  All other tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Edited the path to have an up to date JDK at the beginning before compiling.